# Can I get Trello for internal use?

Tags: trello

My company's going to want to bring Trello internal if we want to use it for confidential data.  Can you bring Trello internal, by running the software on our own server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Rich Armstrong, Director of Customer Operations

> there are no plans to offer a self-hosted version in the future.

As described in their [privacy section](https://trello.com/privacy)

> Access to your data is tightly controlled internally. Unless we hear
>   different from you, we will only be able to access and view the
>   information you make public. We do run anonymous usage profiling over
>   our database, but no one can inspect your data without your say-so.

This line does not say how well they will handle confidential data but that is a risk you are going to have evaluate based on the critical nature of your data.

Comment: "Access to your data is tightly controlled internally."  "no one can inspect your data without your say-so."- Does this mean encrypted?

Comment: @Marc no, it does not mean that. It means, per company policy, the select individuals that have the technical means to see your data would need to get your permission first.

Answer (score 3):

No. We have no current plans to make Trello an intranet app.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Not Trello, but there exists this [open-source Trello clone named Wekan](https://github.com/wekan/wekan) that you can host yourself on your own server, [Sandstorm](https://sandstorm.io/) and many cloud-as-a-service providers.