# Can I run Trello on my local server?

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get Trello for internal use, like stack exchange?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23136/can-i-get-trello-for-internal-use-like-stack-exchange)

Can I run Trello on my local server? If so, what are the requirements?

Answer (score 3):

No, according to [Trello Blog / Trello Common Questions (September 14, 2011)](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/):

> Can I install this on my own server?
>
> No. I can say with a lot of certainty that we don’t plan on doing this. We believe that the majority of people are becoming more comfortable hosting their services and the boost in dev productivity we get by only having one platform to test on is immense.