# Where are the Trello servers located?

Tags: trello, legal

In which country, or countries, are servers running Trello located? Because of the laws in Canada regulating public institutions, we are not allowed to store certain kinds of information if the servers are in the USA.

A solution would be to run this nice tool on our own servers, but I just read [that this is not an option](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23136/can-i-get-trello-for-internal-use-like-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The Trello servers (including the databases) are hosted on Amazon Web Services (EC2, in the United States)
- The Trello javascript/CSS are hosted on amazon cloudfront (with edge nodes around the world)
- Attachments that are uploaded to Trello are stored on Amazon S3, but in a US region.
- Google Drive/Docs attachments that are attached to Trello cards are (of course) hosted wherever Google stores its files.